# Save Text Boxes to Text File and Load Text File Content in Textboxes (Serialized) Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, serialization, outputstream

What I'm trying to do is save information from the text boxes into a text file. When the text file is loaded the text boxes will be filled up with information. When saving the file I'm getting this error via an Exception e.printStackTrace(); Thanks

[image]

```js
 private void savecustButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     Customer customer = new Customer();
     try {
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Customers/" + custidTF.getText() + ".txt");
       ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

       customer.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));
       customer.setPersonSurname((custsurnameTF.getText()));
       customer.setPersonID((custidTF.getText()));

       oos.writeObject(customer);
       oos.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {

     }

     dispose();
```

```js
private void loadCustomerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  Customer customerfile = null;

  try {

    final JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("Customers/");
    int chooserOption = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    chooserOption = JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION;

    File file = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
      new FileInputStream(file)
    );

    customerfile = (Customer) in .readObject(); in .close();

  } catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error loading file.");
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("Invalid class in loaded file.");
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you able to get any further information from `IOException ex`?

Comment: No just the 'Error loading file'

Comment: You can get more information from an [`IOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html), e.g. with `getMessage`...

Comment: Ok it returned this ' Error loading file.writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: procject.Customer ' I think the load is fine but the save is messed up. Its not saving properly i think.

Comment: when I use your code separated, on a ad hoc created Customer class it works fine (unless by readable, you mean readable and understable text). I can save to .txt, open .txt, and load .txt file. What is 'procject.Customer'?

Comment: .NotSerializableException: airline.booking.system.Customer - its the program that im working on... and so with my code it worked fine? it was loading the name etc... in the text fields? Thanks

Comment: @Luke_i please add e.printStackTrace(); to catch part in save methods, and show us result

Comment: Attached image of the error I'm getting with the e.printStackTrace();

Comment: @Luke_i so your Customer class is not serializable at all, you cant save and load, am I right, that you didnt implement serializable?

Comment: I edited my class with implements Serializable and when saving the file I get no errors now :) , but still the file is not loading. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your Customer class don't implements Serializable interface. Add `implements Serializable` to class opening statment.

Comment: I edited my class with implements Serializable and when saving the file I get no errors now :) , but still the file is not loading. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you try to read data form Customer customerfile textfields?

Comment: What do you mean by read data from Customer customerfile textfields? The text wrtten in the textfileds is being saved into the text file, than when loaded it giving the Excpetion error. I want to load the object.

Comment: After testing the Load again its not giving any errors. Even with the e.printStackTrace();  The text boxes are still staying empty though. Thanks

Comment: but textboxes in GUI, or the fields of customerfile?

Comment: the GUI text boxes are staying empty.. like nothing happened. The save text file is not readable but the values inputted are at the end of the file so it is saving correctly I assume.